# Read Image from numpy and display it: ValueError: conversion from L to PNG not supported

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a 2D array of an image (**slice**). The array dimension is (224, 224) and when I read it as an image as shown below, ***the image mode is shown as "F"***, for some reason I need to save as "PNG" and display it. I'm gettig error message "ValueError: conversion from L to PNG not supported"

The real image is shown below. See the below code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import cm

# reproducible data
slice = np.ones([224, 224], dtype = float)
print(slice.shape)

img_m3= Image.fromarray(slice)#.convert('RGB')#.convert('PNG')

print("img .mode",img_m3 .mode)
if img_m3 .mode != 'PNG':
   img_m3  = img_m3.convert('PNG')

img_m3.save("/tmp/myimageb.png", "PNG")

im = Image.open("/tmp/myimageb.png") 
plt.imshow(im    )#, vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

Update:

I also tried saving it as JPG, no errors, but I got blank image:

```
if img_m3 .mode != 'RGB':
    img_m3  = img_m3.convert('RGB')
    
    img_m3.save("/tmp/myimageb.jpg", 'JPEG')
    
    #plt.imshow(img  ,  cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
    im = Image.open("/tmp/myimageb.jpg") 
    plt.imshow(im    )#, vmin=0, vmax=255)
    plt.show()
```

[image: original image]

Update2:

I tried the solution on the answer, now I can see the image. But the quality degraded. See below, on top is the original image and bottom is the result.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
print(image[0].shape)
print("slice.max()",slice.max())
print("slice.min()",slice.min())
print("slice.mean()",slice.mean())

slice.min() and slice.mean()
#img = Image.fromarray((slice*255).astype(np.uint8)).convert('L')
img =  Image.fromarray(slice.astype(np.uint8))

img.save("/tmp/myimageb.png", "PNG")
plt.imshow(img  )#,  cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()


    (224, 224)
    slice.max() 0.5193082
    slice.min() -2.0836544
    slice.mean() -0.37065452
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: "PNG" isn't an image mode in PIL - see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#modes. But PIL can save images in various modes to PNG format, including mode `L` (see https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png). What happens if you just remove the line that calls `.convert` ?

Comment: If your image mode is `F` it is floating point. So you either need to save to a format that can handle floating point (e.g. TIFF or PfM) or convert to 8 or 16-bit integer and save as PNG.

Comment: I tried to convert to slice.astype(np.uint16) but getting same error.

Comment: when remove the convert, I get error: OSError: cannot write mode F as PNG

Comment: What do you mean *"I tried the solution on the answer"*? Please show the actual code you used. Also, remember `matplotlib` does all manner of scaling, contrast-stretching and colorising images - try looking at the result in a normal image viewer. Also try printing `slice.max()`, `slice.min()` and `slice.mean()` so we can see the range of your values.

Comment: updated question with code and values @MarkSetchell

Comment: Aha! There's the problem - your numbers go below zero and are not in the range 0..255. PNG cannot support negative numbers, so we'll need to scale differently or use a TIFF.

Comment: If your numbers are always in the range `-1...+1`  we could add 1 to bring them to the range 0...2 then multiply by 127.5 to bring them to the range 0..255 and store in a PNG. Or if you want better resolution, we could add 1 then multiply by 32767.5 and store in a 16-bit PNG.

Comment: The safest option is a TIFF really then your values will be stored absolutely correctly with no need to scale on saving and reloading.

Comment: It worked fine with scaling, but I had to use "astype(np.uint16)" instead of astype(np.uint8). I couldn't make work with TIFF though,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It transpires that the pixels are both float AND potentially negative, so you probably want an image format that can store such things which is TIFF.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Make single channel 224x244 image of floats in range -2...+2    
slice = np.random.uniform(low=-2, high=2, size=(224,224))

# Convert to 224x224 to PIL 'F' Image
im = Image.fromarray(slice)
im.save('result.tiff')
```

Just a couple of notes:

- TIFF files can get rather large because they are uncompressed by default, so you might want to try different compression [options](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#) to see if anything suits your data
- OpenCV also has a [FileStorage](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d56/classcv_1_1FileStorage.html) format - but this is not readily viewable by other programs
- OpenCV supports OpenEXR format for floats too and this is quite readily viewable by other software

**Original Answer**

The following should work fine for you:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Make single channel 224x244 image of floats in range 0..255    
slice = np.random.rand(224,224) * 255

# Convert to 224x224 array of uint8 and then to PIL 'L' Image
im = Image.fromarray(slice.astype(np.uint8))
im.save('result.png')

print(im)        # prints <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=224x224>
```

[image]

Comment: I had to use astype(np.uint16) instead of astype(np.uint8)